# How do I fix the error Native JS does not support indexing when trying to append an element into a list python

Tags: python, while-loop

Given a sequence of non-negative integers, where each number is written in a separate line. The sequence ends with 0. Print the index of the first maximum of the sequence.

so I am trying to append those element into a list, and encouters the error Native JS does not support indexing, how do I fix it?

```
n = -1
lista = [] 
while n!= 0:
    n = int(input())
    lista.append[n]
print(max(lista), lista.index(max(lista)))
```

this is my idea, but lista.append[n] is untrue

Answer (score 0):

From a quick scan of your code I see you're not calling the `append()` method correctly. `lista.append[n]` should be `lista.append(n)`